# Controlling movement without GPS

Tags: dronekit-python

I was trying to use the DroneKit-Python API to control the movement of a drone. I've been reading what it's in [that link](http://python.dronekit.io/guide/copter/guided_mode.html), but I can't find what I need. I want to be able to run the code with the dron indoors (and of course outdoors), so I can't rely in the GPS. I've tried to eliminate that part and use only the *send_ned_velocity()* method (without the propeller). But I couldn't hear a significant change in the movement of the engines.

The only way I can think of is using the *channel_override*, but it doesn't seem to be the better choice. Can anyone help me?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`send_ned_velocity()` will only work if you are in guided mode.  With Arducopter 3.3, you can only be in guided mode if you have a gps lock.  So you aren't going to be able to use this command indoors.

You'll have to wait for 3.4 to be released, then guided mode will be supported without gps. But instead of gps, you will need an optical flow module and a rangefinder installed and configured.